# How to do a paymaster from scratch?

Tags: smart-contract-wallets, account-abstraction, erc-4337, paymaster

I just read and learned about the account abstraction concept, and I like it when I know it has a gas-less concept (paymaster).

During reading and implementing, I have some questions:

1. If I start building my paymaster for my little project, should I need to implement a bundler? If yes, assuming I will build on Polygon zkEVM, should I stake MATIC into the bundler, and how much?
2. For example, I have a custom smart contract, with the logic inside it. I want to apply paymaster to it, how can I calculate `callData`, and `paymasterAnData` (which means I will build a user operation with paymaster)

`const paymasterAndData = hre.ethers.utils.hexConcat(["paymaster address", hre.ethers.utils.hexZeroPad("token address", 20),]) const callData = MyToken.interface.encodeFunctionData("transfer", ["receiver", 100_00_00_00_00]);`

3. For example, I am the owner of the SimpleAccountFactory contract, each time at the backend I create a new smart account, should I need to use a different private key?

Thanks in advance!